# Replacing \citet and \cref with a single command (acme of laziness)

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, natbib, cleveref

What would be the easiest way to accomplish the following?  I want a single command, say `\vcref`, which automatically becomes `\citet` if all of its arguments are in the list of references and otherwise becomes `\cref`.  No `you don't want to do this` comments please.  Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\bibliographystyle{whateverstyle}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{refcite}
\begin{equation} \label{myeq}
 y=x
\end{equation}
\citet{ugh} found that \cref{myeq} can hold.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't wnat to do this. (Sorry, I couldn't help it.)

Comment: very funny ;)))

Comment: (but yes, I do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a proponent of addressing "should" after "could". You could go the other way (check if any of the arguments is a label, as defined by `r@key`) fairly easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{whateverstyle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}        

\makeatletter
    \def\omniref{\@ifnextchar[{\citet}{\@ifstar{\citet}{\omni@ref}}}
    \def\omni@ref#1{%
        \newif\iflbl\lblfalse
        \def\do##1{\@ifundefined{r@##1}{}{\lbltrue}}%
        \docsvlist{#1}%
        \iflbl\cref{#1}\else\citet{#1}\fi}
    \AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{autonum}{\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{omniref}}{}}
\makeatother

%

\begin{document}
\bibliography{refcite}
\begin{equation}\label{aeqn}
 y=x
\end{equation}
\omniref{vanLoosdrecht99} found that \omniref{aeqn,eqn2} can hold.

\begin{equation}\label{eqn2}
 y=x
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[{van Loosdrecht and Henze(1999)}]{vanLoosdrecht99}
van Loosdrecht, M. C.~M., Henze, M., 1999. Maintenance, endogeneous
  respiration, lysis, decay and predation. Water Science and Technology 39~(1),
  107--117.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Assuming the bibliography entries are defined as `b@citekey`, the approach you proposed is doable as well. If *all* of the entries are cited in the bibliography, the following will use `\citet`; if not `\cref` will be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{whateverstyle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}        

\makeatletter
    \def\omniref{\@ifnextchar[{\citet}{\@ifstar{\citet}{\omni@ref}}}
    \def\omni@ref#1{%
        \newif\ifbib\bibtrue
        \def\do##1{\@ifundefined{b@##1}{\bibfalse}{}}%
        \docsvlist{#1}%
        \ifbib\citet{#1}\else\cref{#1}\fi}
    \AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{autonum}{\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{omniref}}{}}
\makeatother

%

\begin{document}
\bibliography{refcite}
\begin{equation}\label{aeqn}
 y=x
\end{equation}
\omniref{vanLoosdrecht99} found that \omniref{aeqn,eqn2} can hold.

\begin{equation}\label{eqn2}
 y=x
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[{van Loosdrecht and Henze(1999)}]{vanLoosdrecht99}
van Loosdrecht, M. C.~M., Henze, M., 1999. Maintenance, endogeneous
  respiration, lysis, decay and predation. Water Science and Technology 39~(1),
  107--117.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image: example]

As for the "should": Obviously this deviates from convention and may make interpreting errors more difficult. The biggest potential issue is if you have a label and a citation with the same key, which may result in unexpected behavior. However, if you are using sufficiently different naming conventions for labels and citations such that you would still be able to infer the intention of the command and eliminate overlap (e.g., `eqn:somthing`, `fig:somethingelse` and `Doe98`) and you are aware of the other potential issues, I'd say go for it.

**Edit**

Since `\citet` accepts options and has a starred variant but `\cref` does not, an additional line was added to each to differentiate the two (if `\omniref` is followed by a star or has options, the `\citet` is used, otherwise the keys are compared). Also, missing `%`s were added to remove the additional white space.

**Edit**

As per the comments below, added compatibility with `hyperref` and `autonum`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  (+1)  I'm going to test this and will $\checkmark$ afterwards.  The first solution would be fine.

Comment: Absolutely totally awesome!  You should turn this into a package!  (Yes, my labels are sufficiently distinct that there is no chance of confusing the two.)  The only downside is that it breaks with hyperref :(.

Comment: But it seems to work if I load hyperref before cleveref.  Hmmm.

Comment: `cleveref` is an [exception](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1868/89497) to the "rule" of load `hyperref` last.

Comment: Thanks.  Your first approach works better.  It doesn't work with `autonum`, but that is to be expected.

Comment: Looks like it gets dicey with the required load order. You also need `amsmath`. Required order: `amsmath`, `hyperref`, `cleveref`, and `autonum`. Finally, `\omniref` has to be registered with `autonum` using the `\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL` command. I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: phenomenal!  How come you don't have 100k points?  Again, ought to be a package.